# How do I add the recently viewed products box to the homepage?

Tags: magento, layout, content-management-system, sidebar

It is a totally easy problem, but Im not able to solve it.

I tried the following:

add layout xml to the update layout field in the backend for this cms page:

```
<reference name="right">
  <block type="reports/product_viewed" before="right.permanent.callout" name="right.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
</reference>
```

or the same in the local.xml

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="right">
      <block type="reports/product_viewed" before="right.permanent.callout" name="right.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Thanks a lot, I know its not complicated, but I cant get it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some checks:

1. Check if your page is using two-column-right or three-column layout.
2. Clearing cache
3. Add your layout update to cms.xml directly and clearing cache.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed to echo the block in the custom home page template file?

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('right.reports.product.viewed');
```

Or may be your home page is using 2-template left or other templates where there is no 'right' content block.